# Effect of image resolution on visual word features

Tags: image-processing, feature-engineering, functional-data-analysis

I have trained and tested an image classifier using visual words (bagoffeature MATLAB) for a simple disease/no disease classification.

However, my disease set is from a different camera (50dpi) from my no-disease image set (70dpi). These were used to train and test whether the image is from either class using the output from bagofFeatures function. The output is the frequency of which a feature (or word) occurs in that image. My algorithm is working well...too well. I think there is such a clear difference between the diseased and no diseased images not because of the disease manifestation but rather the resolution may be affecting the feature ("words") vector that have been extracted.

I've been searching high and low for the maths for this and can't seem to find an explanation to why it would effect the feature vector. Anybody have any idea as to the effects of resolution on feature vectors. Or could anyone explain anything I may be missing?